# Is it possible for a country to grow its economy without foreign investment?

Tags: economy, foreign-direct-investment

China's economic development is often heavily attributed to direct foreign direct investment (FDI) during the late 70's through 90's.

Is FDI absolutely necessary for a country to grow its industry?

If a country doesn't have plenty of natural resources like gulf countries or Russia, can that country grow its economy at a substantial pace FDI?

I know that it is a very important component of an economy. But, is it the only way for a country's economy to grow?

Comment: Can you give a source or reference for your first sentence?

Comment: @quarague, https://youtu.be/SGJ5cZnoodY   ----- https://youtu.be/_sV5P_F3frY

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, foreign investment is not *necessary* for an economy to grow. Consider the world as a whole: it has never had any outside investment that we know of, but its economy has grown massively over the past few thousand years.

China's economy was able to grow *faster* because of outside investment. Notably, production lines in use in other countries were moved to China to take advantage of the lower labour costs.

Answer (score -6):

> Is it possible for a country to grow its economy without foreign investment?

Absolutely YES!

The Soviet Union developed at an incredible pace prior to 1953 without FDI. As did China prior to 1976.